# using Dictionary Key (as a string) to set variables in a constructor

Tags: c#, reflection

Rather than making numerous overloads of a class constructor, I would like to pass in a `Dictionary` to dynamically set variables.

```
// Class definition
public class Project
{
    public DateTime LastModified;
    public string LoanName;
    public string LoanNumber;
    public int LoanProgram;
    public string ProjectAddress;
    ...

    // Project class constructor
    public Project(Dictionary<string, object> Dict)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in Dict)
        {
            // ie, when the Key is "LoanName", this.LoanName is set
            this.(entry.Key) = entry.Value;   // <-- Does not compile, obviously
        }
    }
}

// application code
...
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
dict.Add("LoanName", "New Loan Name");
dict.Add("LoanProgram", 1);
dict.Add("ProjectAddress", "123 Whatever Way");
Project p = new Project(dict);
...
```

In the constructor, is there any way to use the Dictionary Key (a string) to determine what class member to set?  Can this be done using reflection somehow?

Comment: This sounds extremely silly.

Comment: What benefit is this getting you? You have to populate a dictionary with specifics keys and values, and then pass it as a parameter in a constructor and figure out how to use it. Why not just pass in the values to begin with?

Comment: Or, use an `object initializer` for that matter.

Comment: I was not actually sure I would take this approach (especially because it does introduce unnecessary complexity), but came across it and was curious as how to solve it.

Comment: @Pubby - dig the sparkles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Project
{
    public DateTime LastModified;
    public string LoanName;
    public string LoanNumber;
    public int LoanProgram;
    public string ProjectAddress;
    ...

    // Project class constructor
    public Project(Dictionary<string, object> Dict)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in Dict)
        {
           this.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Key).SetValue(this, entr.Value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile to note that using reflection will incur a performance penalty.  This is not an invalid approach, of course, but the consequences should be made known.

Comment: Then of course you need to deal with dictionary keys for members that don't exist, aren't public, aren't of the right type, are static, etc.

Comment: Right, but the correct answer already given by cdhowie, this just a trick about "how can we set property values by property name". He can check all cases, catch exceptions about that. just an example.

Comment: Based on the many comments above, I agree that this method is far from ideal, but @TufanBarışYıldırım - thank you for the response

Answer (score 11):

The fields are already public... why not just use object initialization syntax?

```
var p = new Project() {
    LoanName = "New Loan Name",
    LoanProgram = 1,
    ProjectAddress = "123 Whatever Way"
};
```

Comment: @Servy Agreed.  Though the initialization approach will be the same with fields and properties.

Comment: @Servy - I simplified the code above, but do in fact have private fields and public get/set accessor methods.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a maintenance nightmare but you can look up the property this way.

```
var prop = typeof(Project).GetProperty(entry.Key);
```

Then you could set the value like this.

```
prop.SetValue(this, entry.Value);
```

You get no compile time type checking this way though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into default parameters.

e.g.

```
public Project(loanName = null, lastModified = null, loanNumber = null, loanProgram = 0, projectAddress = null)
{
    //Set them in here
}
```

I would also recommend using public properties instead of public fields.
e.g.

```
public DateTime LastModified { get; private set; } //Makes it so only inside the class LastModified can be set
```